# On click function is not working on safari browser

Tags: javascript

On click function is not working on safari browser. If anyone knows, please help me with that.

Html:

```
<span  class="dropdown" onclick="javascript:drop()"></span>
```

Script:

```
function drop(){
    if(document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style.display=="block"){
        document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style="display:none";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style="display:block";
    }       
}
```

Comment: What about other browsers ? is it working ?

Comment: @RayonDabre other browsers are working fine

Answer (score 0):

> You do not need `javascript:` while assigning inline events to `span` elements.

`style="display:none"` is not a valid syntax.

*Note:* `element.style.display` will only read inline applied css properties..

> Use `getComputedStyle` to get *values of all the CSS properties*

Try this:

```js
function drop() {
  if (document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdown" onclick="drop()">Hey!</span>

<div id='dropdown-content' style="display:block">Target Element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Safari mobile?

In my experience, both Safaris have had issues with click events, usually because they want a 'tap' event.

The easiest way to get around this. Is by using something like jQuery which will apply a bunch of different events to make sure it works properly.

Otherwise, you could try duplicating the onclick and making an ontap.